# aggregate functions (count, sum, ...) broken (Jaspersoft Studio 5.5.0.final and 5.5.1.final)?

Tags: jasper-reports, aggregate-functions

(I added the basic **problem solution and the underlying understanding** in the **bottom part of my answer (marked by: <sup>1</sup>)**, underneath the two example report graphics!)

---

All I actually like to have is a **`DISTINCT COUNT`** on a **`String` column field**, but it **seems** to me that **all the aggregate functions** behave as if they are **simulating** the **`FIRST(...)`** functionality.

I can't believe this is broken and it seems more likely I am missing something very strange here.

(I am quite experienced already with JasperReports and worked with BIRT and other reporting frameworks before as well.)

Looking at the docs I can't see where the problem should be: http://www.jasperassistant.com/docs/guide/ch06s08.html

Finally I created the **attached** [simple sample report](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/questions/test-report.jrxml) (and now **[another test-report-ext.jrxml](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/questions/test-report-ext.jrxml)** which enhances this one with better structure, markers and sql-generated comparison data) based on the sample db and updated to the latest 5.5.1.final release without any progress.

Please anybody tell me the secrets I am missing or to my big surprise assure it's a bug indeed. :-(

Thx

Andreas :-)

as you can see in the report there is just some `page header` and `summary bands`, containing the `product id/name/cost` labels, the `name count`, `cost count`, `cost sum` and all **variations of** name count `increment types` (`report/column/page/none`). the `summary band` holds the `cost sum`. the `detail band` contains just the `detail fields`.

But none of the aggregate functions shows aggregated data, but only the `first(xxx)` result it seems. (so strange anyways that the `count(name)` shows the first rows `name` column value instead of a `number` :-( ).

(I also posted this question in the Jasper forum and will keep both up-to-date on important posts: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824152/aggregate-functions-count-sum-broken-jaspersoft-studio-550final-and-551final )

[image]

---

## example report solution

[solution for summary and header bands by user12...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22094435/1915920) solves the problems and at the same time shows, how confusing<sup>1</sup> the setup can be (showing the result of [test-report-ext-fixed.jrxml](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/questions/test-report-ext-fixed.jrxml)):

[image]

---

## <sup>1</sup> clarifications of correct and confusing setup

I'd like to add some infos for others like me, (or maybe for myself, in case I have to do it again after a while and forgot about the specialities ;-) ) which may be confused and mislead by the provided setup options, the underlying logic, the (Eclipse) Jasper Studio tooltips and the docus refered to in the first part of my answer...

the **correct understanding/setup** (as I understand it):

- there can be **`variables`**, which can be (re)evaluated at certain generation steps and
- there can be **`text fields`** (which can be based on those variables), which can be updated at certain generation steps
- using **aggregate functions** ...

  - the **`variables`** need to be declared with a **`Reset Type`** of NOT! `NONE` (e.g. **`Report` (default if not provided (in XML)), `Column`, `Page`**)

    - meaning this is when the variables value will be recalculated during generation phase
  - the **`Value Class Name`** must match the **`type of the final, aggregated result`**

    - **e.g. `Calculation = Count` => `Value Class Name = java.lang.Integer`**
    - it **can be confusing<sup>2</sup>** in situations where `java.lang.String` will work here as well :-/

      - e.g. if `Reset Type` is set to `None` and the generated report will show it in a `Title Band` as a `String`, probably similar to the behaviour of the `First` aggregate function
    - it is **even more confusing and misleading<sup>2</sup>** since setting `Reset Type` to `None` (e.g. while playing around to get it fixed) for a `Count` on a `String` field with a previously (correct) setup of `Value Class Name = java.lang.Integer`, would cause some `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number` if not adjusted to the (normally) incorrect `Value Class Name = java.lang.Integer`
    - **e.g. `Calculation=Sum` => `Value Class Name = java.lang.Float`**

      - if the underlying sums are based on atomic `Float` values
    - e.g. `Calculation=Sum` => `Value Class Name = java.lang.Integer`

      - if the underlying sums will always be castable to an `Integer`
    - e.g. `Calculation=Sum` => `Value Class Name = java.lang.BigDecimal`

      - if the underlying sums can be quite "large"
  - the **`text fields`** may have to be set to an **`Evaluation Time`** other than **`Now`**, e.g. **`Report`** if their position in the report is **not in a `Summary Band`** or before their value is/can be calculated looking at the underlying data processing steps (`ResultSet` iteration I would say).

    - it **can be easily forgotten<sup>2</sup>** to realize this functionality if one assumes that this may be somehow automatically happen based on the underlying used `Variables`

      - e.g. using some `Count` in a `Title Band` although the `Variable` is set up correctly
  - the **`Increment Type`** is **only relevant**, if some **`Incrementer Factory Class Name` is provided**

    - it **can be confusing<sup>2</sup>** in situations where this can be set without any effect, although no factory is given and one may thus mix it up with the `Reset Type` semantics :-(

<sup>2</sup>: This should be especially addressed by stricter Jasper Studio input validation, the mentioned docs and the Jasper Studio tooltips!

Comment: added link to the enhanced simple report that more clearly shows the problems towards the sql-generated correct data

Comment: added results jpg above and an editional html-version

Comment: there had been a minor (rather unrelated) mistake in the `test-report.jrxml` and `test-report-ext.jrxml` where the `CostCnt` was set to `calculation="Sum"` which I fixed in the `test-report-ext-summary-band-fixed.jrxml` setting it to `calculation="Count"` (`CostSum` is there which already did this anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting resetType to "None" is probably your problem (at least for the IdSum). Not sure why it ends up being 38 though. Set resetType to "Report" or to nothing(Report is default) for it to work:

```
<variable name="IdSum" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression>$F{ID}</variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Same goes for the variable CostCnt, although it is going to be a normal sum and not a distinct one.

If this ends up solving your problem please post the solution into the forum as well.

You can fix the calculated fields in the header just by changing your TextFields Evaluation Time from Now to Report
Change

```
<textField>
    <reportElement uuid="d30afc9a-40bc-4d5a-a4eb-15bf4f881acd" x="100" y="18" width="50" height="20" forecolor="#FF0000"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NameCntNone}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

to

```
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement uuid="d30afc9a-40bc-4d5a-a4eb-15bf4f881acd" x="100" y="18" width="50" height="20" forecolor="#FF0000"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NameCntNone}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Do this for every TextField and you should see the calculated values.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not work for my scenario, but fixes the summary band stuff in my sample report (which I attached along with the fixed jrxml on the forum site). See the picture in my question above, where all the header info is now nulled :-( Likely I missed some other point (aggregation only possible in summary bands?) And regarding the `Reset type` *"None - variable is never reinitialized"* (as in the docu linked in my question) suggests to me, that it is initialized once. Do you know what this means actually?

Comment: Can you post the jrxml to the 2nd screenshot? Mabye i can see why those values are null.

Comment: it was attached to the question in the Jasper forum: http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/questions/test-report-ext-summary-band-fixed.jrxml

Comment: Hi user1232141, will you be able to have a look at it or clarify that it won't work in my scenarios by design? If so I would like to accept your answer for the question.

Comment: @AndreasDietrich I have updated my post to include the solution to your problem with the calcualted fields in the header. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated my answer with the correct solution and tried to clarify some confusing parts there.

Answer (score 0):

I forget to mention some simple solution, in case somebody has a similar problem with "broken", strange or insufficient aggregation functionality, at least if you have some Oracle database underneath or similar aggregation functionality:

One could just **aggregate the data on the query level** (of course not related to report pages etc.), which may have advantages or disadvantages (memory footprint, network/io traffic, expertise, ...), e.g.:

```
select 
  x.*, 
  sum(distinct name) over () as name_cnt_distinct,  -- of all results
  count(distinct cost) over () as cost_cnt_distinct,  -- of all results
  count(*) over () as row_cnt,  -- of all results
  sum(cost) over (partition by trunc(cost/10)) as cost_sum_per_cost_range_10  -- per cost range 0..10, 10..20, 20...
from product
where id < 20
```

(which in my case will be fine as well)

Additionally if you use some filtering functionality in your reports and calculations based on the **filtered data** (like me), a database view like the above may not be helpful (since it does not know the filter settings before hand).

Oracle provides some **`parameterized view`** (thinking here of a **"filterable view"**) functionality for this called [**`table functions`**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm) that come in quite handy in such situations and can help to **separate information generation logic (database engines are good at this) from display/layout/graphics/internationalization logic (report engines are good at this)**